# cpp deleting old pointer and re-initializing it

Tags: c++, pointers, boost

i have a tcp server, which requires to allow exactly one client to connect to it at any time. anytime a new client connects, older session must be deleted and new session created.

right now, i am doing it like this:

```
void TcpServer::start_accept() {
    Logger::info("[TCPSERVER] TCP Server starting to accept", __LINE__, __FILE__);

    if (session) { // check if there is any older session, if so..delete them
        session = NULL;
        delete session;
    }

    session = new TcpServerSession(io_service_);
    acceptor_.async_accept(session->socket(), boost::bind(&TcpServer::handle_accept, this, session, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}
```

so any time i would like to send a msg to the client, it is being done like this:

```
int TcpServer::sendMsgToClient(std::string msg) {

    if (session)
        session->sendMsgToClient(msg);
}
```

i am wondering if this is being done correctly? basically the main point is deleting a pointer and re-creating it.whats the best way to do this?

Comment: The order of your delete and null-assignment is backwards. as-written, you're leaking memory like a sieve leaks water.

Comment: I hope this code if (session) { // check if there is any older session, if so..delete them
        session = NULL;
        delete session;
    } is not in your product?

Comment: That order is **entirely** wrong. First `new` a new session object (exception? Old session is still there), then swap the new and old sessions, then delete the old session. There is not a single nanosecond during which `session` should be `nullptr`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (session) { // check if there is any older session, if so..delete them
    session = NULL;
    delete session;
}
```

This is totally wrong! You blank out `session`, leaking whatever is currently there, and then `delete` `NULL`, which does absolutely nothing.

To be exception safe, you should not `delete` the old session until you have successfully created the new one. Something like this:

```
if (session) {
    // Create and initialise the new session first
    TcpServerSession* newSession = new TcpServerSession(io_service_);

    // Don't know what this line does, but I assume it's important
    acceptor_.async_accept(newSession->socket(), boost::bind(&TcpServer::handle_accept, this, newSession, boost::asio::placeholders::error));

    std::swap(session, newSession); // Put the new one in place
    delete newSession; // delete the old one.
}
```

Actually, this assumes `async_accept` doesn't throw. If it can, you will need to be careful to delete the `newSession`, probably with some kind of smart pointer.

Answer (score 5):

Just use a `std::unique_ptr<>` :

`session.reset(new TcpServerSession(io_service_));`

It gets everything right: don't delete old object before a new one is available, never have session point to something invalid, and even in the presence of exceptions no memory is leaked.

Answer (score 2):

```
    session = NULL;
    delete session;
```

Is most certainly not correct. If you replace the value that `session` holds (which points to a block of memory allocated by `new`) **before** calling `delete` on it, you effectively lose that block of memory, causing a memory leak. The only reason why this code doesn't blow up is because calling `delete` with a `NULL` is guaranteed to be a no-op.

Thus, you should replace the code with the following :

```
    delete session;
    session = NULL; // or nullptr if you've got C++11
```

Which will guarantee that the memory is properly freed.

Comment: As Barmar suggested, assigning a NULL is pointless in this case, since the value is instantly overwritten without being read anyway. My bad.

Comment: Not quite as bad as you think. If the `new` or constructor throws an exception the new pointer value will never make it into `session`. Without the old one cleared out, you're going to hit this, or some other cleanup code, that tries to delete the same value again. And NULL/nullptr isn't a solution, per'se; a smart pointer is.

Comment: @WhozCraig : having so far worked in C++ projects where exceptions are explicitly disabled, I tend to forget about them quite frequently. Thanks. And, of course, you're 100% right about the smart pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `session = NULL` before `delete session`. You're trying to delete the null pointer.

You don't need to set it to null because you're immediately going to set it to the new TCP session.

Comment: Actually, you should, because `new` might throw and leave session in an inconsistent state. But `BoBTFish` has the better solution there; don't delete the old before the new session is created.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (session) { // check if there is any older session, if so..delete them
    session = NULL;
    delete session;
}
```

This code says:

**If session points to some valid object** (instead of being null), then **stop pointing to it** (instead, point to NULL), and then delete what session now points to, i.e. **delete *nothing***.

This is very bad. It is a genuine memory leak.

The comment is a lie.